# Can you use the Password Policy Authenticator isconnector when logging into the Dahsboard?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using the isconnector Password Policy Authenticator https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/502efeb1-cc59-4b62-a197-8c612797933c
with a new deployment of WSO2IS. The documentation for the connector only applies to how to set it up for the individual SP's. In our environment the user logs into the user dashboard area first and clicks on one of our custom dashlets to get the the SSO resource. Since the user is already authenticated at that point the SP configuration does not seem to matter. Is there a way to setup this connector for dashboard login?
Thank you
Kirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service provider config for the dashboard application is added via a configuration file. (`<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/service-providers/sp_dashboard.xml`).

You can add the second step to the configuration in the file. So the config would look like this.

```
...
        <AuthenticationSteps>
            <AuthenticationStep>
                <StepOrder>1</StepOrder>
                <LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                    <LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                        <Name>BasicAuthenticator</Name>
                        <DisplayName>basicauth</DisplayName>
                        <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                    </LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                </LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                <SubjectStep>true</SubjectStep>
                <AttributeStep>true</AttributeStep>
            </AuthenticationStep>
            <AuthenticationStep>
                <StepOrder>2</StepOrder>
                <LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                    <LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                        <Name>password-reset-enforcer</Name>
                        <DisplayName>password-reset-enforcer</DisplayName>
                        <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                    </LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                </LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                <SubjectStep>false</SubjectStep>
                <AttributeStep>false</AttributeStep>
            </AuthenticationStep>
        </AuthenticationSteps>
...
```

Note the step 2 I have added in the above config. That is the additional part you need to add to the config.

PS: As kirk has mentioned, you have to restart the server to get this config to work.

Comment: This worked perfectly Maduranga. Thank you for taking the time to help a new WSO2 admin out! The only thing I will add is that this will require a reboot/restart of IS. Warmest Regards, Kirk